# Catalan number application in arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways in which n '1' and n '2' can be arranged in a row that up to any point in the row numbers of '1' is more than or equal to numbers of '2'.

This is the same question asked by me in August 2017, and the answer was that it is a Catalan number.

Me and my team are trying to prove this result but not able to deduce the result which is the Catalan Number. I just need to prove that the result is the CATALAN NUMBER.

Comment: Dyck words satisfy Catalan recurrence

Comment: It might help if you state your definition of a Catalan number.

Comment: Consider each one of you '1' characters a '(' character and each '0' character a ')'. The number of desired sequences becomes the number of correct parenthesis sequences of length 2N, which you can prove is the the Nth catalan number. Correct parenthesis sequences are equivalent to dyck words and you can find the proof for the correspondence on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics). I recommend reading the 5th proof of the formula.